# Data structure internal implementation

Tags: javascript, data-structures

If we implement a DataStructure in JavaScript, will the browsers underlying implementation use same data structure for handling data?

A Linked List for example - we will have a Node structure something like this

```
class Node {
    constructor(data) {
       this.data = data;
       this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Now let's say we set `next` to another node to create a linked list.

Does `next` really point to next Node using Linked List in underlying implementation? Linked List has O(1) to add a new node. Will this be actually same O(1) for JavaScript too when C++ (or any JavaScript engine) converts the implementation to system level ?

Comment: depending on how you write your List class, this will have O(1) no matter how it's compiled/cross-compiled/interpreted. it does a constant amount of work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, identifiers (variables and arguments) and properties of objects are all essentially *pointers* to structures in memory (or on the heap).

Say that you have two Nodes like in your code, one linked to the other. One way to visualize the resulting structure is:

```
<Node>: memory address 16325
  data: memory address 45642 (points to whatever argument was passed)
  next: memory address 62563

<Node>: memory address 62563 (this is the same as the `next` above)
  data: memory address 36425 (points to whatever argument was passed)
  next: memory address 1 (points to null)
```

That's not *exactly* what happens, but it's close enough for the "underlying implementation" you're concerned about. If, in your JavaScript, you have a reference to one Node, and you link it to another by assigning to its `next` property, what's involved under the hood is simply taking the location of the linked object and changing the original object's `next` property to point to that location. And yes, that operation takes next to no processing power - it's definitely an `O(1)` process in any reasonable implementation, such as in browsers and Node.

The JavaScript engine does not have to re-analyze the structure from the ground up when a new property is created somewhere - it's all just objects and properties linking to other objects.